# Warn when Outlook add-in is not enabled

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-2013

Since upgrading to Office 2013, we have some issues with an Outlook add-in disabling itself. I know that the time it takes to start can be an issue, but while we've done everything possible to speed it up, the fact it is a .net add-in means that, on our systems, we cannot get it to start faster than 1 second - the threshold beyond which Outlook disables it automatically.

We previously modified the add-in to catch all exceptions in all interfaces by default. The add-in should never pass an exception back to Outlook, but I have seen the odd occasion where Outlook's internal interface has crashed, disabling the add-in.

The add-in itself is critical to the way part of our application works - outgoing emails are intercepted and scanned, and if they meet certain criteria, uploaded to a document management system automatically. The users love it, except when it doesn't work.

I know when the add-in gets disabled, Outlook is meant to warn the user via a notification bar, but this doesn't always happen, especially in Citrix, where users don't have the requisite permissions to enable or disable add-ins.

Ideally what we would like is some way to warn a user when the add-in is not enabled. Obviously the add-in can't do this, because if it's not enabled it can't warn the user that it's not enabled. Does anyone know of another way of doing this?

Comment: What about starting a second add-in, maybe written in VBA, to simply check if the addin is available. If not, simply throw an error or maybe try to resurrect it.
Ideally, contact the MS team about the performance problems, they might have an idea.

Comment: VBA add-in is an interesting idea. Would that be faster to start, or not subject to the same performance limitations? What about an Office app as well? I haven't looked in to those much.

Comment: Personally, I have only written VBA-Addins (there was never the need for a big c# addin), and they are quite fast to start - so there should be no problem. There would be timing issues, but clever use of polling etc. would prevent that.

Comment: Also can a VBA add-in be rolled out easily across 500ish desktops?